# A book about a girl waking up to a 'same but different' life after having a bad fight with her boyfriend by the water

Tags: story-identification, parallel-universe

Looking for the title of this book (10+ years back). A girl wakes up to what seems like her life but there are discrepancies that can't be explained. She and her boyfriend had fought the night before, but the details are hazy and he won't talk about it. She starts having *deja vu* and follows what she feels are clues. She recognises a man (David maybe?) but she can't figure out where she knows his face from. She approaches him and asks if she can talk to him, wanting answers.

Her boyfriend has been following her and sees her with David. I can't remember the details but it was basically history repeating itself. Turned out that what she 'forgot' about the fight was that her boyfriend had drowned her in the river in a jealous rage over seeing her with another man, the other man being David. Her boyfriend's name started with a 'C', I think. I have this feeling her name might have been Sarah or Elizabeth, but I'm probably wrong. Thank you

Comment: Some details are confusing. Did she herself die, or the previous "she" in the new life?

Comment: She finds out that her 'original' self died. She didn't realise she was in a different dimension, there were just lots of inconsistencies that made her question what had happened the night they had fought. Flashbacks of drowning and the like

Answer (score 4):

I think this might be "[Sudden Switch](https://www.amazon.co.uk/d/cka/Sudden-Switch-Time-Twists-Paul-McCusker/0745936113)" by Paul McCusker.

The main character is a teenage girl who has a near-drowning experience in a bathtub, and wakes up in an alternate dimension. She tries to convince people that she is someone else (because she has memories of her previous world, but doesn't understand what happened) and her parents/doctors/etc. believe that she has amnesia. Eventually, it turns out that the version of herself that was native to her current dimension was drowned by her boyfriend in a jealous rage. This near-death experience caused a shift in the fabric of space-time, allowing the two versions to swap places. Neither girl died, because the dimensional switch saved the drowning girl's life.

I think the "deja vu" effect you described has to do with the point when the main character begins to remember aspects of her alternate self's "murder". It could also have to do with all the main character's explorations of the alternate reality.

The person the main character recognizes (David) is the alternate universe version of her best friend/love interest.
"Calvin" is the murderous boyfriend.

---

Note: apparently the book has been republished under the name "***Ripple Effect***", which might be why it's difficult to find.